# Azure DevOps Server 2020 - @mentions have stopped working

Tags: notifications

On-premise Azure DevOps Server 2020. Recently @mention's in work items have stopped generating email notifications in one of my collections DBs. However, email notifications do get generated when assigning a work item (for example). There is no Subscription that I can see which corresponds to the @mention's so I am unsure what settings control them or how to troubleshoot this problem. Any suggestions?

In a work item, entering @username does not generate an email notification to that user. But assigning a work item does generate an email.

This was working fine for all users until a few weeks ago. The issue is not specific to one user.

I haven't fully tested all default subscriptions but as noted above the **A work item assigned** subscription is working OK. Also @mentions are working in another of our collection DBs (on the same server) so the problem seems specific to one collection.

[image]